# Check all invalid table dependencies and recompile them dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I Modified two columns of a table and now I have invalid dependencies, I need to check all of them and recompile dynamically

Originally it was

```
CREATE TABLE AHO_CUENTA_AHORRO 
(
    ID_CUENTA NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    ID_SOCIO NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,
    ESTADO VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    TASA_INTERES NUMBER(3,1) NOT NULL,
    FECHA_APERTURA DATE NOT NULL,
    FECHA_CANCEL DATE,
    SALDO_BLOQUEADO NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,
    SALDO_DISPONIBLE NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_ID_AHORRO PRIMARY KEY (ID_CUENTA)
);

ALTER TABLE AHO_CUENTA_AHORRO 
    ADD CONSTRAINT SOCIO_CUENTA_AHORRO_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (ID_SOCIO)
        REFERENCES SOC_SOCIO (ID_SOCIO);

ALTER TABLE AHO_MOVIMIENTOS_CUENTA 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CUENTA_AHORRO_MOVIMIENTOS
        FOREIGN KEY (ID_CUENTA)
        REFERENCES AHO_CUENTA_AHORRO (ID_CUENTA);
```

and now i added this

```
ALTER TABLE AHO_CUENTA_AHORRO
ADD (
SALDO_REAL  NUMBER(12) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
ID_TARIFARIO NUMBER(15) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FK_TARIFA FOREIGN KEY (ID_TARIFARIO) REFERENCES TARIFARIO(ID))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To identify the invalid objects, you could run the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE status = 'INVALID';
```

You could then manually compile them one-by-one using the DDL below:

```
ALTER <object_type> <object_name> COMPILE;
```

For example:

```
ALTER VIEW some_invalid_view COMPILE;
```

This approach might work well if you only have a few invalid objects without many dependencies.

Another approach would be to call the procedure below, which compiles invalid objects in the specified schema in dependency order.

```
DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => '<your_schema>', compile_all => false);
```

The `compile_all => false` compiles just the invalid objects.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73226